# How to convert android Object to String[]?

Tags: java, android

I have 2 variables inside Object object, when I print it using toString() it showed me {"name"="some_name","phone"="some_phone"} , is it possible to convert that object into string[0] = name and string[1]=phone?

```
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Object object = listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

            }
        });
```

Comment: `getItemAtPosition` returns an `Object` so what is the actual data type of your data

Comment: `String[0] = (String) object.name;`?

Comment: @LunarWatcher `Object` class doesn't have a `name` field so error

Comment: Given @FarellSujanto 's Object array, yes

Comment: the object is from list view's data , so how to take the data from list view to string? I need it for details activity and to search in the DB

Comment: how about you show us the code u used to create your adapter and data array/list

Comment: here it is http://pastebin.com/uEeF4W1q

Comment: declare `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> albums;` as global and later use `albums.get(position);`

Comment: @PavneetSingh thanks it worked out well

Comment: i am glad that i could help , happy coding

Answer (score 1):

That really depends on the class you're using to represent your items, if you'r storing them inside a list of `HashMap` as you indicated in the comment, you should cast your object to a `HashMap`, then you can easily access the keys and values of that hashmap:

```
HashMap<String, String> album  = (HashMap<String, String>) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
String name = album.get("name");
String phone = album.get("phone");
// you can store them in an array
String[] attrs = {name, phone};
```

**edit :** you can also make your `albums` variable global, then you can replace the first line with simply:

```
HashMap<String, String> album = albums.get(position);
```

Comment: thanks @PavneetSingh & nabil i've combine both of your codes and it works flawlessly